# An elegant way to make a list of functions in python

Tags: python, list

[edited]
For example I have a function and I have different values of y.

```
 def h(x):
    return x*y
```

I tried appending h(x) in my list,say y = 3. However, when I change y to another value and append h(x) again in my list, the y in my first h(x) has also changed.

Example:

```
>> func_list = []
>> def h(x):
>>    return x*y
>> y = 1
>> func_list.append(lambda x:h(x))
>> func_list[0](5)
>> 5
>> y = 2
>> func_list.append(lambda x:h(x))
>> func_list[1](5)
>> 10
>> func_list[0](5)
>> 10
```

Is there a nice way to do it since I can't make lots of h(x)'s with different y values?

Comment: Please provide a little more code.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Could you provide a short **complete** program that sort-of does what you want? http://SSCCE.org

Comment: I The code (from original post) was actually it is. It was just the execution of changing value of y affecting the previous values of y's in the h(x) already in the list. Anyway, there. I edited it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your `y` probobly lives in a closure (BTW: what about a *working* minimal exmple?), you'll have to wrap a layer around it:

```
def mk_func(y):
    def h(x):
        return x * y
    return h
```

and then

```
my_funcs=[mk_func(i) for i in (1, 3, 4, 7)]
```

.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`functools.partial`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) for this:

```
import functools

def h(y, x):
    return x * y

func_list = [functools.partial(h, y) for y in [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]]
print [f(3) for f in func_list]
```

Comment: And the production of the list here is a [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw).